# WCF not working inside form class

Tags: c#, forms, wcf, endpoint

I followed this tutorial for basic WCF inter-process communication:
http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication

I have a client and a server that both work as console applications (as the tutorial creates).

But when I have moved my WCF server code into my form, it does not work.

Console Application server code (Working fine as console app):

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IModelData
{
    [OperationContract]
    ArrayList GetData();
}

public class ModelDataServer : IModelData
{
    public ArrayList GetData()
    {
        return new ArrayList(); // Just for testing that it works (before form version)
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(
        typeof(ModelDataServer),
        new Uri[]{
            new Uri("http://localhost:8000")
        }))
        {
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IModelData),
                new BasicHttpBinding(),
                "ModelData");

            host.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("Service is available. " +
                "Press <ENTER> to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();

            host.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I read that there is a problem with WCF and windows forms if you start ServiceHost on the UI thread. [running WCF in windows forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009608/running-wcf-in-windows-forms) < this told me that I could fix the issue with UseSynchronizationContext=false as below, but I'm still having issues.

My form code:

```
public partial class ServerForm : Form
{
    ModelDataServer Server;
    public ScraperForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Server = new ModelDataServer(); // this should start the server?
    }

// other stuff
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IModelData
{
    [OperationContract]
    ArrayList GetData();
}

[ServiceBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext=false)]
public class ModelDataServer : IModelData
{
    ServiceHost Host;
    public ModelDataServer()
    {
        using (ServiceHost Host = new ServiceHost(
        typeof(ModelDataServer),
        new Uri[]{
          new Uri("http://localhost:8000")
        }))
        {
            Host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IModelData),
              new BasicHttpBinding(),
              "ModelData");

            Host.Open();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList GetData()
    {
        return GetData();
    }

    public void CloseServer()
    {
        Host.Close();
    }
}
```

I don't believe that my Host is being garbage collected in the above example because it's a field. Am I correct?

The error I'm getting when calling this server from my client (working with the above console app) is as follows:

```
There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:8000/ModelData that could accept
the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See
InnerException, if present, for more details.
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Show your web.config code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using (ServiceHost Host = new ServiceHost(
    typeof(ModelDataServer),
    new Uri[]{
      new Uri("http://localhost:8000")
    }))
    {
        Host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IModelData),
          new BasicHttpBinding(),
          "ModelData");

        Host.Open();
    }
```

You're opening your service host inside a using block.  There's nothing after the `Host.Open();` statement, so your `using` block is exited and the host is closed.  Hence no endpoint is listening.

You'd be better off (in this instance) skipping the `using` block and opening and closing the service host explicitly.  You should be able to hook into one of the application ending events to close the host on application exit.

Comment: Because I had made Host a field of the class, I thought that it wouldn't be disposed after the using. Thank you.